# Prevent UIImagePickerController from saving images

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am building a simple app where I get an image from `UIImagePickerController` (from Camera or Photo Library, depends on user selection) and send it to a server.

The latter seems to be saving images on the App internal folder, because when I take any photo, in the Disk Debug Menu in Xcode, I can see every time 1 - 1,5 MB writing on Disk. The same happens for images from Photo Library, they too occupy about 1 MB.

This is the code, very basic:
(VisualRecognition is the IBM API to use one of their AI services)

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
var imageShot = UIImage() //To send later the image to the server

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let userPickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    imageShot = userPickedImage
    picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.elaborateImage(self.imageShot). //The sending function
    }
}

func elaborateImage(_ image: UIImage) {
    animateIn()
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let visualRecognition = VisualRecognition(version: self.version, apiKey: self.apiKey)

        visualRecognition.classify(image: image, acceptLanguage: self.language, failure: { (error) in
            print("There was an error")
        }, success: { (classifiedImage) in
            let classes = classifiedImage.images.first!.classifiers.first!.classes

            var classificationResults = [ScanResult]()

            for index in 0..<classes.count {
                let scan = ScanResult.init(score: Int(classes[index].score! * 100), name: classes[index].className)
                classificationResults.append(scan)
            }

            self.sortedClassificationResults = classificationResults.sorted(by: {$0.score > $1.score})

            group.leave()
        })
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToResults", sender: self)
    }

}
```

After sending the images to the server *I don't need anymore them*, but **they continue to grow the app size**.

How Can I stop `UIImagePickerController` from saving images inside the App Bundle?
Thanks

Comment: i think it keeps image in var just make it nil after sent. and what does elaborateImage method do share that code too for more clarification.

Comment: I've added more information in the post. Anyway, the _imageShot_ var should be resetted on every app launch, but in Settings > General > Free iPhone space I can see Documents and Data growing on every usage